# Black Body radiation and radiation in general

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, thermal-radiation

---

So I'm learning about blackbody radiation and radiation in general. As I understand it, there are 3 ways to transfer energy/heat: Convection, Conduction and Radiation. In chemistry I also learnt about the emission spectrum of Hydrogen. I understand that when light is shot at a bunch of Hydrogen atoms some of the electrons will absorb a specific wavelength and will jump to a higher energy level/orbital and then drop back down releasing energy in the form of light of the same wavelength it absorbed - (wavelength directly corresponds to the level of energy it carries - shorter wavelength means its more wavy which means more energy).Hydrogen only has 1 energy level so depending on the amount of energy an electron absorbs it will go to the 2nd/3rd/4th etc. and then fall back to the 1st level because it only has the first level.

[image]

Below is the black body emission spectrum - it is 2d (2 axis, x and y) compared to the 1d emission spectrum of Hydrogen, why? Does the y axis indicate the intensity of the wavelength? But wait - wavelength is already an indicator of intensity/energy. Perhaps by intensity it means the wave is longer from start to finish? (waves have length right)

I do not understand the difference between the absorption spectrum of hydrogen and its (ideal) black body radiation. Why would hydrogen be able to emit all kinds of radiation even though it can only absorb discrete levels of energy? Clearly, the black body radiation spectrum tells me that with varying efficiency, hydrogen could emit all kinds of radiation.

Thanks - lots of questions.

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that a sample of hydrogen can emit a blackbody spectrum?

Answer (score 0):

Why is the blackbody radiation graph 2d? The graph is 2d because it is a plot of the intensity of radiation versus the wavelength of the radiation, thus it establishes a relationship between two parameters of interest. The intensity of radiation is in the quantum case, the number of photons; a quantity which corresponds to the overall level of brightness or luminosity of the source. So the blackbody plot tells you how much radiation (related to number of photons) of each wavelength (related to frequency) is present.

You write that: "hydrogen only has one energy level", however, this is untrue. Although hydrogen atoms only have one electron, the hydrogen atom itself has an infinite number of energy levels that can be characterized by the quantum number $n$, where $n$ denotes the particular energy level. It is true that the energy levels are discrete and have spacing between them, this fact accounts for the discrete emission/absorption spectrum of hydrogen and other atoms, the most probable transitions occur between these lower energy levels, however, for larger $n$ the discrete levels are packed so tightly that they are nearly continuous as the energies approach $-13.6\text{eV}$ (the ionization energy for H). The reality then is that although certain transitions are more probable than others, many other frequencies apart from those that comprise the typical emission spectrum may be emitted. The emission/absorption spectrum is a signature that informs you of an element's presence, but it is not the whole story.

A blackbody is an object that is in thermal equilibrium such that it is absorbing all radiant energy incident upon it and in turn emitting the same so that it's temperature remains constant. The intensity of the continuous band of frequencies emitted by a blackbody of a given temperature is given as a distribution known as the Plank radiation law,
$$\text{Intensity}={\hbar\over\pi^2 c^3}{\omega^3\over e^{\hbar\omega/\tau}-1}$$
i.e. the graph for blackbody radiation in your post. Where $\omega$ is the frequency, $\tau$ the absolute temperature and $\hbar$ and $c$ are important fundamental constants. In reality, the Plank radiation law only holds for true blackbodies, which are quite idealized. Notice that apart from the frequency, the Plank radiation law depends only on the temperature, and not on what kind of material the body in question is composed of, e.g. the same graph is drawn for hydrogen gas as for iron for some given temperature.

Essentially, the Plank radiation law is a statistical law that takes into account the behavior of a vast ensemble of atoms. If one could examine a few atoms at a time the spectrum emitted by the small collection would indeed be discrete, however, for a vast ensemble of atoms at some level of thermal equilibrium, a continuous band of radiation is emitted as described by the Plank radiation law. In practice, this law is only an approximation to the spectrum emitted for bodies at some temperature because the bodies in question are only approximately black, no actual material truly absorbs and emits all frequencies, although some come quite close. Despite these shortcomings, the Plank radiation law and the blackbody concept is useful in estimating the temperature of objects like stars, where the only direct access researchers have to them is the light that can be collected by telescopes for example.

Comment: Check this picture out: https://ibchem.com/IB16/Section02-atomic/img/H-series.gif
Suppose we had a blackbody made out of pure hydrogen. Would we then theoretically have a line spectrum of the Lyman series since it would absorb some wavelength of light and then jump up only to return to n = 1 since its most stable like that?

Also as a side note, doesn't this emission spectrum make the assumtion that we are hsooting light of all wave lengths at it? If we only shot a small range of them there would only be so many ways that it could absorb and release light?

Comment: Blackbody radiation is a thermal property that depends only on the absolute temperature of the hydrogen, so any specimen of hydrogen will emit blackbody radiation unless cooled to absolute zero.  One should expect to observe Lyman series spectra whenever the hydrogen is sufficiently energetic.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the figure's axises are "Wavelength" and "Spectral Radiance", not x and y. BTW: they're the abscissa and ordinate, respecively. Note that you have "y" versus wavelength, and the formula is different vs frequency, and it's again different if "y" is number of photons per slice in "x"...so be wary when using and comparing "THE Black-Body Curve", there is no "THE".

I think you're taking the quantum description too literally, which happens a lot in QM. The atom absorbs the photon and changes energy (approximate) eigenstates. It's not just the electron that's in an orbital, it's also the nucleus (see: reduced mass). Nevertheless, saying it's the electron is fine, just remember it's shorthand.

And it doesn't jump up/fall down, the atom changes among its infinite number of available states, with the photon energy being equal to the difference in the energy of those states. Only a small number of transitions are in the visible, though, and those mostly (if not all) involve the ground state as the final state.

The atomic spectra is a property of the atom, so you don't need a bunch of them as stated in the question. A single atom will absorb and emit at the allowed frequencies.

A single atom cannot emit black body radiation--it doesn't even have a temperature. That is a property of bulk material, and to emit visible light you need to be over the Draper temperature (idk, 787K?, anyone?)...pretty hot.

Comment: I've been thinking of light and radiation in terms of waves since we were talking baout wavelengths. This maybe a stupid question but if wavelength is a property of light is the length of a wave also a property? What is the length of these sinusoidal waves?